# how can i run my fetch process with other functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript

I`m not familiar with javascript. And actually, I have a basic idea. I want to make some requests and while these requests are continuing, I want to process the incoming data in another function.

That is my fetch function. It's kinda recursive. after 5 requests it will end.

```
      function loadNextContainer() { 
       
       var url = "sample_videos/container" + numberContainer; 
       if(numberContainer>4){
        
         return; 
       }      
       fetch(url)
       .then(response => response.blob())
       .then(data =>  {  
         console.log("fetched");
         //i ll add the fetched data to array or something else
        })
       .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          });   
          numberContainer++;
          loadNextContainer();
   }
```

And you can imagine that this is the process code.

```
  async function loop1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    
    await null;
   
  }
}
```

And output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
fetched
fetched
fetched
fetched
fetched
```

And this is what i want:

```
fetched
0
fetched
1
fetched 
2
3
fetched
4
fetched
```

It is not important that they work in order. They just need to work together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Promise.all()`, that should solve your problem, in the code snippet below both the functions `fetch1` and `fetch2` run simultaneously.

```js
const fetch1 = async() => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  const json = await res.json()
  return json
}

const fetch2 = async() => {
  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
  const json = await res.json()
  return json
}

const main = async() => {
  const results = await Promise.all([fetch1(), fetch2()])
  console.log(results)
}

main().catch(e => console.log(e.message))
```